# Unable to establish a connection to a database of SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2012

When connecting to SQL Server error occurred with the network or to a specific instance

```
The server was not found or is not available.
Verify that the instance name is spelled correctly 
and that SQL Server allow remote connections. 

provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - 
Error detection specified server or instance.
```

The connection string to the database:

```
<add name="RequirementContext" 
    connectionString="Data Source=RU-DEV24;Initial Catalog=OpenSoft.AgileAnalytics.EF;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I can not understand, which is why this error occurs. Help please!

Code in which an error

```
public class Permission
    {
        public string RoleString
        {
            get
            {
                return string.Join(", ", UserRoles);
            }
        }

        public int UserId { get; set; }

        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public List<string> UserRoles { get; set; }

        public static Permission CreateFromUserProfile(UserProfile userProfile)
        {
            //here
            return new Permission
            {
                UserId = userProfile.UserId,
                UserName = userProfile.UserName,
                UserRoles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(userProfile.UserName).ToList(),
            };
        }
    }
```

**!!!!
The problem was solved. I just added to file web.config this code:**

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SimpleRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="SimpleRoleProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider,WebMatrix.WebData" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <membership defaultProvider="SimpleMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="SimpleMembershipProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

Comment: Which version and edition of sql server are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Version 11.00.3153

Comment: is the SQL is local or remote ? try 1)  disable firewall 2) if remote , "allow remote connection"

Comment: disabling the firewall does not help,
remote connection allowed. No decision has not helped

Comment: if you connect with using Window Auth , the 2 computers must be on the same domain . try with user/password auth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Make sure that your database engine is accepting remote connections:**

- **Start** > **All Programs** > **SQL Server 2012** > **Configuration Tools** > **SQL Server Surface Area Configuration**
- Click on **Surface Area Configuration for Services and Connections**
- Select the instance that is facing the problem > Database Engine >
  Remote Connections
- Enable local and remote connections
- Restart the instance

**Enable TCP/IP in SQL Server Configuration:**

- Go to **Start** > **All Programs** > **Microsoft SQL Server 2012** > **Configuration Tools** > **SQL Server Configuration Manager** > Select **TCP/IP**.
- Right click and select **enable**

**Make sure that the SQL Browser service is running:**

- On the Start menu, right-click **My Computer**, and then click **Manage**.
- In **Computer Management**, expand **Services and Applications**, and then
  click **Services**.
- In the list of services, double-click **SQL Server Browser**.
- In the SQL Server Browser Properties window, click **Start** or **Stop**.
  When the service starts or stops, click **OK**.

**Configure your windows firewall to allow access :**

- On the Start menu, click **Run**, type **WF.msc**, and then click **OK**.
- In the Windows Firewall with Advanced Security, in the left pane,
  right-click **Inbound Rules**, and then click **New Rule** in the action pane.
- In the **Rule Type** dialog box, select **Port**, and then click **Next**.
- In the **Protocol and Ports** dialog box, select **TCP**. Select Specific
  local ports, and then type the port number of the instance of the
  Database Engine, such as **1433** for the default instance. Click **Next**.
- In the **Action** dialog box, select **Allow the connection**, and then click
  **Next**.
- In the **Profile** dialog box, select any profiles that describe the
  computer connection environment when you want to connect to the
  Database Engine, and then click **Next**.
- In the **Name** dialog box, type a name and description for this rule,
  and then click **Finish**.

Comment: I have consistently done everything that you have written. Unfortunately, the same error in the same place in the code

Comment: look at the last part of my answer and perform those steps and see if that helps

Comment: Unfortunately, recent actions also did not help in solving the problem. There is the same error.

Comment: @ТатьянаДрузенко - i would suggest you uninstall sql server and perform a fresh clean install once again, and after that please go through all these links - 1> http://www.linglom.com/it-support/enable-remote-connection-on-sql-server-2012-express/ , 2> http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/335874/A-network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occur , 3> http://serverfault.com/questions/601317/cant-connect-to-sql-sever-management-express-2012, 4> http://sevennet.org/2014/11/24/how-to-enable-remote-connections-for-sql-server-express-2012/, 5> http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=195517

Comment: I think that the problem is not in the sql server. All data from the database and displayed on the pages only an error in the method. Everything else works fine.

Comment: Okay, on which line in your code does the error occur?

Comment: //here                                                                                                                                       
            return new Permission
            {
                UserId = userProfile.UserId,
                UserName = userProfile.UserName,
                UserRoles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(userProfile.UserName).ToList(),
            };                                                                                                                                  Last method

Comment: Error here:                                                                                                        UserRoles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(userProfile.UserName).ToList()

Comment: Glad , you got the solution, there is also an other solved question somewhat similar to yours on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14521003/mvc4-userisinrole-unable-to-connect-to-sql-server-database

Answer (score 0):

Common causes of this error:

1. The server named in the connection string doesn't exist (misspelled, etc.)
2. Server is unavailable (off-line, etc.)
3. Server is unreachable (try pinging the hostname to verify these first 3)
4. Server is not configured to allow network access
5. Windows Firewall (or other security software) is blocking access to the SQL Server port
6. SQL Server instance name not specified or incorrect (in the example above, the connection would fail unless you're using the default instance on your sever)

If you're using SQL Express, you should probably have "SQLEXPRESS" as the instance name for your server.

Comment: 1. pinging the hostname: connection to the server passes 2. All data are derived from the tables on pages, then the name is spelled correctly. The error code at this point:                                                     `code`public static Permission CreateFromUserProfile(UserProfile userProfile)
        {
            return new Permission
            {
                UserId = userProfile.UserId,
                UserName = userProfile.UserName,
                UserRoles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(userProfile.UserName).ToList(),
            };
        }`code`

Comment: I do not use SQL Express