# Enable Role Manager mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a MVC 5 Project.

I want to use `Roles.GetAllRoles()`.

But i get the `System.Configuration.Provider.Exception`.

I tryed to solve it with modifying the `Web.Config`, but i still get the error.

```
<appSettings>
<add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
<roleManager defaultProvider="CustomRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="CustomRoleProvider" type="MyProjekt.CustomRoleProvider" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>    
<authentication mode="None" />
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
```

I also tryed to add

```
<roleManager 
enabled="true" 
cacheRolesInCookie="true" >
```

but then i get

> An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in
>   System.Web.dll    but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: No Connection with SQL Server-Database.

Comment: does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14525353/1849444) helps you?

Comment: [InitializeSimpleMembership] is missing... How can i get this?

Comment: Am i correct that you use SimpleMembershipProvider?

Comment: I´m using Individual User Accounts in Mvc 5, i don´t rly now if i use SimpleMembershipProviders

Answer (score 0):

I got caught out by this for a while Roles.IsUserInRole("Admin") which sent me down the route of looking for role providers etc.  I should of just been using User.IsInRole("Admin")
the following was a usefull article in enabling roles 
http://geekswithblogs.net/MightyZot/archive/2014/12/28/implementing-rolemanager-in-asp.net-mvc-5.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I know this maybe does not pertain specifically to your question, but I just discovered how to find the Role a particular User is assigned to:

```
    Dim userInfo = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId())
    Dim userRole As String = userInfo.Roles(0).RoleId
    Dim thisRole As String = db.Roles.Where(Function(x) x.Id = userRole).FirstOrDefault().Name
```

That was bugging me for a while so I just had to get it out there!