# Hide and visible the div tags of Layout.cshtml on the basis of user role in Asp.net MVC4(Razor)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having a master page which is having some menus for a Role called user and other menus are for the role of Admin, So what i am willing is to check the role of the user and and show some div tags and hide others on the basis of user role.

**As, we don't have controller for layout.cshtml, so how i can set the viewModel for layout view
Wherein i can check the role of the current user**

How to do role based checking on the layout.cshtml.

I have been through followin question but it has not been answered by now

[How to Show or hide controls based on roles - ASP.NET MVC 4 Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11829937/how-to-show-or-hide-controls-based-on-roles-asp-net-mvc-4-razor)

So,Please tell me the possible solution and which way would be the best for applying role based checking in layout.cshtml

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use the [`User.IsInRole`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iprincipal.isinrole.aspx) method:

```
@if (User.IsInRole("admin"))
{
    <li>Only the admin can see this menu item</li>
}
```

Comment: Ok,let me try but i am using SimpleMembership so will it work

Comment: Yes, it will work. Obviously you need to have a role provider configured, because the membership provider is not dealing with roles.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Following code for role based checking

```
@if(Request.IsAuthenticated)

{
    if(User.IsInRole("Admin")
    {
     <Ul Class="SubMenuItem">

     <li> this menu item is for Admin role</li>
     </Ul>
    }
     if(User.IsInRole("User")
    {
     <Ul Class="SubMenuItem">

     <li> this menu item is for User role</li>
     </Ul>
    }
}
```

> For unknown user

```
else
{
 <Ul Class="SubMenuItem">

     <li> this menu item is for Unknown user</li>
     </Ul>
}
```