# AspNet, how to hide certain roles from certain privileges

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a web application in which certain users can assign certain roles to other users.
I have a number of roles for e.g. Admin, Super User, Developer, Designer
The Admin and the Super User can assign roles.

Is there a way in the View, where If I am a `Super User` the `Super User` checkbox does not show? subsequently, The `Admin` cannot assign to himself `Super User` or uncheck `Admin` for obvious reasons

Basically. This is what they should have access to:

```
Super User: Admin, Developer, Designer
Admin: Developer, Designer
```

This is the coding being used at the moment.

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Roles", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <span class=" col-md-10">
            @foreach (var item in Model.RolesList)
            {
                <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedRole" value="@item.Value" checked="@item.Selected" class="checkbox-inline" />
                @Html.Label(item.Value, new { @class = "control-label" })
            }
        </span>
    </div>
```

This shows all the roles found inside the database irrespective of role. What can I change please?

Thank you in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide and visible the div tags of Layout.cshtml on the basis of user role in Asp.net MVC4(Razor)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15609463/hide-and-visible-the-div-tags-of-layout-cshtml-on-the-basis-of-user-role-in-asp)

Comment: Didn't think of using IsInRole for this purpose. Thanks for the idea. Worked like a charm