# Manually Hide 'Admin' Menu Tab in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, windows-authentication

I will like to hide the 'Admin' Tab in Layout view when user access it.
Only user has Admin role is able to see the 'Admin' tab.
Anyway to get the query result and return to Layout view so the view can determine the user is Admin?

I'm using Window authentication mode, which is get the user windows id as username. No login page is required.

At the same time, i have create an admin page to add user name as admin.

Role Model:

```
[Key]
public int Role_ID { get; set; }
public string Permission_Role { get; set; }
```

User Role Model:

```
[Key]
public int Permission_ID { get; set; }     
public int Role_ID { get; set; }
public string Role_User { get; set; } <==== will stored @User.Identity.Name
```

Layout.cshtml:

```
<div class="menu">
    @if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        <nav>
            <ul id="menu">
                <li>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Home", "SURV_Main_Home", "SURV_Main", null, new { @id = "home" })
                </li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("New Survey", "SURV_Main_Create", "SURV_Main", null, new { @id = "create" })</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Survey List", "SURV_Main_Index", "SURV_Main", null, new { @id = "list" })</li>
                if (query get user name is admin then just show this tab) <=======
                {
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Admin", "SURV_Admin_Home", "SURV_Admin", null, new { @id = "admin" })</li>
                }
            </ul>
        </nav>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: i cont get it ..What U need

Comment: hi @JagadeeshGovindaraj, i will like to hide the Admin tab in layout.cshtml if the user role is not admin.

Comment: @if (User.IsInRole("admin"))
{
    <li>Only the admin can see this menu item</li>
}

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide and visible the div tags of Layout.cshtml on the basis of user role in Asp.net MVC4(Razor)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15609463/hide-and-visible-the-div-tags-of-layout-cshtml-on-the-basis-of-user-role-in-asp)

Answer (score 1):

Just do the following:

```
<div class="menu">
    @if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
    <nav>
        <ul id="menu">
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "SURV_Main_Home", "SURV_Main", null, new { @id = "home" })</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("New Survey", "SURV_Main_Create", "SURV_Main", null, new { @id = "create" })</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Survey List", "SURV_Main_Index", "SURV_Main", null, new { @id = "list" })</li>
            if (User.IsInRole("admin")) <=======
            {
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Admin", "SURV_Admin_Home", "SURV_Admin", null, new { @id = "admin" })</li>
            }
        </ul>
    </nav>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Another benefit of this - you probably don't want to output the Admin url to non-admin users. Safer to hide it serverside...

Comment: hi ,  How can MVC know current user is admin? Is that i need to perform some query ?

Comment: I would recommend you store the user role with the username in the cookie and just validate on the user role to determine if it is admin or not