# Database model for users with multiple capabilities

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18286793/users-with-different-capabilities/), I explain my goal to create 2 different types of users with different capabilities in my ASP.Net MVC 5 website. I wonder how I would be able to modify my current database models to hold the related information based on their type. My current models are as follows:

```
public class User : IUser
{
    public User()
        : this(String.Empty)
    {
    }

    public User(string userName)
    {
        UserName = userName;
        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }

    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string MobilePhone { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<UserAddress> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class Restaurant
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<RestaurantAddress> Addresses { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<RestaurantFood> Menu { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Review> Reviews { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Url)]
    public string Website { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    public string Fax { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public int Seats { get; set; }

    public double AverageRating { get; set; }
    public double AveragePrice { get; set; }
}
```

One solution that comes to my mind is to move the additional info of the `User` class to another class and hold the foreign key for the related model in the basic user info class. Something like:

```
public class User : IUser
{
    public User()
        : this(String.Empty)
    {
    }

    public User(string userName)
    {
        UserName = userName;
        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }

    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public virtual ExtendedUser NormalUserInfo { get; set; }
    public virtual Restaurant RestaurantInfo { get; set; }
}

public class ExtendedUser
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string MobilePhone { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<UserAddress> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class Restaurant
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<RestaurantAddress> Addresses { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<RestaurantFood> Menu { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Review> Reviews { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Url)]
    public string Website { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    public string Fax { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public int Seats { get; set; }

    public double AverageRating { get; set; }
    public double AveragePrice { get; set; }
}
```

and in controller:

```
    User user = BuildUser();
    ExtendedUser normal = BuildNormalUser();
    Restaurant rest = BuildRestaurant();
    if (model.Type == UserType.NormalUser)
        user.NormalUserInfo = normal;
    else
        user.RestaurantInfo = normal;
```

However, I'm not sure that this is the right thing to do.

Comment: Why you just add a foreign key to your user entity to represent user type...? Show me a clearer example of aim, maybe I can help you ...

Comment: I think I found the answer. I think I should add the foreign key to the extended types. Right?

Comment: It also could be. These days there are several ways to achieve your goal!