# Create Model From Another Controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a complex user type ([more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18286793/users-with-different-capabilities)) which may contain different information based on different types. Now, when I want to register the user, I want to add the necessary information in other database tables. Currently I'm trying to do this:

#### Models:

```
public class NormalUser
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    //....

    [Required]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

#### Controller

```
                if (await Users.Create(user) && await Secrets.Create(new UserSecret(model.UserName, model.Password)) &&
                    await Logins.Add(new UserLogin(user.Id, IdentityConfig.LocalLoginProvider, model.UserName)))
                {
                    var normaluser = new NormalUser(model) { User = user };
                    db.NormalUsers.Add(normaluser);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    //....
```

However, when I run this, I get 2 errors on the last line. One error is saying that the `Id` field of the `normaluser` should be unique and the other is saying that the `User` field should be unique. They are both required criteria, but I thought the first is handled by auto-increment of the `Id` field and I didn't expect the second one since I just created the `User`.

Am I even doing the right thing by using this method?

### Update:

Fixed the first one by changing the type of the `Id` field from `string` to `int`

Answer (score 0):

Well, found my answer. First I had to change the type of the `Id` field from `string` to `int` to enable auto-increment.

And second, I used the newly created `User` object by mistake. I had to load the info from database:

```
var newUser = db.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == user.UserName).FirstOrDefault();
var normaluser = new NormalUser(model) { User = newUser };
```